# cannot use $rootScope.$new() in testing directive

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a unit test for my directive:

```
describe('Directive: ov-tabs', function() {
  var $compile, scope,subScope, element, template, doc,timeout,window;
  beforeEach(module('ngnms.ui.tabs','layout.html'));
  beforeEach(inject(function(_$compile_, $rootScope,$templateCache, $timeout,$document, $window) {
    template = $templateCache.get('layout.html');
    $templateCache.put('template/tab-layout.html', template);
    $compile = _$compile_;
    timeout = $timeout;
    window = angular.element($window);
    doc = $document;
    scope = $rootScope.$new();

    var html =
            '<ov-tabset ov-tabs="items" on-tab-selected="tabSelectCallback" on-tab-closed="tabClosedCallback"></ov-tabset>';

    element = angular.element(html);
    $(element).appendTo($('body'));
    //------------------------------------------init scope
          //add 12 items to scope
    //-------------------------------------------end init scope
    $compile(element)(scope);
    scope.$digest();

  }));
it('some thing true',function(){});
   var lis = element.find('li');
   expect(lis.length).toEqual(12);
})
```

The result throw error for interact with DOM
If i change "scope = $rootScope.$new();" to "scope = $rootScope;" they'll work fine!

I want test sope to `$destroy()`. Because `$rootScope` cannot invoke `$destroy()`

ERRORS log here!
[image]

Comment: every expects i created will throw errors! but if i change to rootScope, it well done. I think it cannot compile the DOM!? maybe

Comment: seriously, *what's the error*

Comment: i have uploaded a image!